# How to Install Perl 6

Tags: installation, perl

I am trying to install [Perl 6](http://www.perl6.org/) and try few programs myself. Unlike other Perl distribution, I dont know how to install Perl 6.

If any one you have already installed it and know the steps, please pass it on. Any links and manuals are greatly appreciated.

OS: Windows Vista. (You can add other platform too, perhaps could be helpful for others(

Comment: Tell us what you have done so far.

Comment: I have downloaded Parrot, then rakudo and tried running the commands as specified here http://perl.bristolbath.org/blog/lyle/2009/04/first-perl-6-experiences.html .. struck in `perl Configure.pl --gen-parrot` ... I dont have Perl5, do I need?

Comment: You will indeed need Perl5 to get started; grab it from Strawberry Perl: http://strawberryperl.com

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, the simplest way is to get the latest [Parrot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/parrotwin32/files/) (download [setup-parrot-2.5.0.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/parrotwin32/files/parrotwin32%20setup/Parrot-2.5.0/setup-parrot-2.5.0.exe/download)) and install it, rather than building the whole thing from source.

Then grab the corresponding Rakudo add-on ([setup-parrot-2.5.0-rakudo-30.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/parrotwin32/files/parrot-rakudo%20addon/Parrot-2.5.0-Rakudo-30/setup-parrot-2.5.0-rakudo-30.exe/download)) from the same SourceForge project; install that in the same location.

Confirm the "Folder Exists" prompt, and then have a look: you'll have a **bin** folder in there containing (among other things) **perl6.exe**

#### Update

This is now much easier since [Rakudo Star](http://rakudo.org/announce/rakudo-star/2010.07) was released.
You can download an MSI installer from http://github.com/rakudo/star/downloads, which installs Rakudo in `C:\Rakudo`
(There's no option to install it anywhere else though.)

Comment: Does it mean I need perl5? I do have the rakudo, but could not able to run it. Is there a step-by-step guide some where? Thanks, you are upvoted.

Comment: I've never tried this on a system without Perl 5, but I'm not sure why it would be necessary. My answer *is* a step-by-step guide - that's all I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 14 will include it in the repos so you will be able to simply install it from the package manager.

Comment: Thanks. But am looking to install this in Windows. :( +1 for the infor.