# How can I run this Perl script in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, script, cmd.exe, perl

I am trying to run a PERL script for the first time.

Here it is : http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-ExtractMain/lib/HTML/ExtractMain.pm

I have never used or worked with PERL before and I am finding the documentation that is given really confusing/difficult to make sense of (it is quite small). I have built it in Windows 7, and ran the

```
./Build test
```

command which is suggested in the README file. It says that it is passed and all dependencies installed.

My problem however, is simple, how do I USE this script?! :) I suspect it might make more sense to people who have used PERL before. To me the documentation is all gibberish.

Would anyone be able to post up an example of how I would use this script please ?

Let's say I have a html page, index.html and wish to extract the main elements from it.

What do I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install Perl 6](http://superuser.com/questions/160011/how-to-install-perl-6)

Comment: @Excellll Nope, Perl is installed and builds correctly. It is running this particular module that I am struggling with. Thanks for pointing me towards this though.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a script, per se, but rather a module.  The module source is linked at the top of the page (the Source link).  You need to save the module to your system to use it.

After that you write your own script that imports this module and then you can use the functions from the module in your script.

The page has a sample script that uses the module.  I've included it below with comments on what it's doing:

```pl
#import the module, make it available to use further down the script
use HTML::ExtractMain qw( extract_main_html );

#define some HTML data, save in the $html variable
my $html = <<'END';
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="nav"><a href="/">Home</a></div>
<div id="body">
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Baz</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
END

#call the extract_main_html function that is defined in the module
my $main_html = extract_main_html($html, output_type => 'xhtml');

#if you get results from the function call, do something with the results
if (defined $main_html) {
    # do something with $main_html here
    # $main_html is '<div id="body"><p>Foo</p><p>Baz</p></div>'
}
```